# What data does Z_SUPER store in iOS Core Data's Z_PRIMARYKEY sqlite table?

Tags: ios, core-data

I had been fighting sqlite in Simulator importing some test data. I finally set up what I wanted, learned about handling Z_PRIMARYKEY.Z_MAX in the process, but I never figured out what data Z_PRIMARYKEY.Z_SUPER is storing (parent/child entity maybe?). I haven't seen anything on SO regarding this but would love to learn more.